# LINQ: select certain object properties Into Same object

Tags: c#, performance, linq

If I have an object A with many properties, out of which I only need a couple, I can boost performance by not transferring unnecessary data, i.e. selecting only the object properties I need into a new type B, either named or anonymous.

Now imagine I want to bind a list of those original objects A to, say, a datagridview, which only displays the couple of properties I want. I have created the datagridview columns using the property names of the original object A and set its datasource type to typeof(A).  I was wondering, if I can select into the same object A just omitting the properties I don't need, i.e.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    .....
    public string propN { get; set; }
}

var list = context.MyObject
       .Select(n => new MyObject { prop1 = n.prop1, prop2 = n.prop2 }).ToList();
```

In this way I don't need to define a new type, either named or anonymous. The question is, do I gain something in performance, or I still have the overhead of the original large object A information, although I do not transfer data for  all its properties.

Alex

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only meaningful performance gain, assuming your constructor is "cheap", is in the SQL and data transport from/to.

That said, not everything is about performance. Sometimes it's about clarity, extensibility, decoupling, etc. Clarity wise, you're forcing others to have to ask the question "Is this property used by the UI?"

In addition to clarity issues, you have coupling between the UI and back-end entities. This is not ideal. A cheap/temporary solution might simply be one like this. Keeping in mind that it's still coupled due to the interface on the class, but it's something that would be trivial to adjust in the future if desired.

```
public interface IMyModel
{
    string prop1 { get; set; }
    string prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject : IMyModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    .....
    public string propN { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<IMyModel> list = context.MyObject
    .Select(n => new { n.prop1, n.prop2 }) // only select these properties
    .ToArray() // execute the query
    .Select(n => (IMyModel)new MyObject { prop1 = n.prop1, prop2 = n.prop2 }); // construct our desired object
```

Comment: I suppose this question originates from my ignorance about decoupling UI from my back-end. If my entities are defined in my back end and I need to show a kind of "dto" objects in my UI, where should those dto be defined (something like the IMyModel of your answer???) ? I presume that both my UI and back-end should know about them, so would I have to define them in a third layer between the two?

Comment: If we assume that you have one assembly for all UI code, a separate assembly containing your data access and entities, then IMyModel and whatever implements it can reside in the UI assembly (or an assembly referenced only by the UI assembly). Somewhere, you need to map from your data object to your UI object, and wherever that happens is where your code needs to know about both.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think, the performance can't improve much as Select statement will go through all your list and create a new list of objects for you. But if you have reference property that you don't use. You can save there.

If there is no complicated logic when you show data to UI. Whey don't you keep the model as it is.

Comment: Some objects have reference properties and others not, but they could have a large string property which I don't need to show in my datagridview.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for UI display only - there is no performance gain. Whatever time you might gain you will lose by creating a new list of anonymous types.

However, if you intend to send this object through the network (as a response to a request for example), then this makes sense. This way fewer properties have to be serialized and sent through the network.

In most cases, however, you should worry with performance to this level. The user won't notice an improvement on such a level. If you really wish to improve the performance of your application, you should profile it and find the hotspots.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should start using some profiling, which I haven't done yet, that will give me a real answer.